# Flutter responsive dimensions values - what is the best approach?

Tags: flutter, themes, responsive

I was looking for the best approach for holding responsive dimensions values in a flutter. I did not find anything that suits my needs. I would like it to be very easy to use and not to check every time what screen size I am at.

I want to avoid this:

```
SizedBox(
  height: isMobile ? _dimensions.gapM : _dimensionsTablet.gapM
)
```

Instead, I want to have this:

```
SizedBox(
  height: _dimensions.gapM // returns 16.0 on mobile or returns 24.0 on tablet
)
```

My solutions to this is to implement singleton `Dimensions` class that takes `context` and initialise all values based on screen size. Here is simple implementation of this:

```
class Dimensions {
  static const int tabletBreakpoint = 600;
  late final bool isMobile;

  late final double gapM;
  ...

  static Dimensions? _instance;

  static Dimensions instance(BuildContext context) {
    if (_instance != null) return _instance!;
    _instance = Dimensions._(context);
    return _instance!;
  }

  Dimensions._(BuildContext context) {
    _initValues(context);
    _instance = this;
  }

  void _initValues(BuildContext context) {
    var shortestSide = MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide;
    isMobile = shortestSide < tabletBreakpoint;
    if (isMobile) {
      gapM = 16.0;
      ...
    } else {
      gapM = 24.0;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then I am initialising or getting its instance it in `didChangeDependencies` in the widget.

**My question is whether there is some easier/better way of achieving something like this? And if not can this approach brings some troubles in long run?** Thanks for the help and opinion.